# Why was this question *not* closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527960/oneplus-one-screen-is-cracked-and-isnt-working-anymore-what-are-the-solutions is clearly off topic. Normally, such questions are closed on Stack Overflow *very* quickly. What happened in this case that it was not closed?

(The Meta Effect will lead to it being closed but at the point of writing it is still open.)

Comment: I imagine it went mostly unnoticed due to its obscure tags.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting on meta every time you see a question that you think should be closed.  Vote/flag for closure and move on.  You should be posting on meta if you're not sure whether or not a question should be closed, or if there is contention among the users on the question over whether or not it should be closed.

Comment: The answer is also rather... special.

Comment: @Servy I don't intend to. It seemed to me like a failure of the system to me so I was curious. I can't vote to close yet.

Comment: @boot4life Then flag it for closure and move on, as I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many hundreds of questions each day that should be closed but aren't.  It's just the reality of the fact that there are way more close-worthy questions than there are people willing and able to close them.

Comment: Very little frustrates me more on SO than seeing the dreaded "3 close votes remaining" message pop up at the end of a day. So few votes, so much more remains to choose from.